# How do I catch delete() methods for the Query Builder in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4

Overriding standard methods (eg. `delete()`, and using hook methods, eg. `Post::deleting()`) are very useful, but it appears that *Query Builder* (or *Fluent*?) objects do not process their methods through these methods.

For example, the following process **will** listen to hooks, and **can** be overridden:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->delete();
```

Where as the following example will not:

```
User::whereId(1)->delete();
```

I could try to make sure never to use the shorthand methods, but preferably, is there a way to catch the `delete()` action in the second example?

Comment: I know that this is not what you are after, but using the `Repository` pattern would greatly help you avoid this type of problems.

Comment: Thanks @GladToHelp, I do not use patterns enough but it does appear to be a solution that I will look into. It still does feel like a slight error in the static calls of Laravel that I should avoid regardless.

Comment: I guess you are right. Maybe you should ask on IRC or check the source code to see why the deleting() event is not triggering. Are you using ModelObservers?

Comment: I just stumbled across this myself. `find(n)->delete()` works but not `whereId(n)->delete()`... frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Model Events are for Eloquent Models processes only. So the event like `deleted`, `deleting` and etc are not in effect since you are calling from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` scope not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. So if you want to fire model events, you need to do it manually. Either change your way of deleting or overwrite on runtime the function `delete` of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Here is my example below:

```
 User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 5])->get(function($model){ $model->delete();  });
```

or much customizable on runtime

```
 $query = User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 5]);
 $query->onDelete(function($builder)
 {
     // Manually fire deleted event which I want since I am deleting the model
     $builder->get()->each(function($model){
                        $dispatcher = $model->getEventDispatcher();
                        $event = "eloquent.deleted: ".get_class($model);
                        $dispatcher->fire($event, $model);
                    });


     // Now proceed with the normal deletion

     // TAKE NOTE: This time you are using
     // Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder not Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder so delete function here will act different.

     // Assuming User model is on soft delete so i just want to make a soft deletion
     $builder->getQuery()->update(['deleted_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
 });
```

So by that example, Eloquent Model Events are being fired.

Comment: That is all based on my understanding upon reading ``Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`` and ``Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder``, which is actually works fine as I tested.